# Prove $|M_{T \wedge n}| \le c + K$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, random-variables, martingales, stopping-times

From Williams' Probability with Martingales

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

1. Is $\sigma_k^2$ random (and not constant)? How can that be? As far as I know unconditional variance and unconditional expectations are supposed to be constant.

---

2. How do we know $|M_n^T| \le c + K$?

This is what I tried:

$$M_n^T = M_{T \wedge n} = M_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{T \wedge n} (M_k - M_{k-1})$$

$$\to |M_n^T| \le |M_0| + \sum_{k=1}^{T \wedge n} |M_k - M_{k-1}|$$

$$\le |M_0| + \sum_{k=1}^{T \wedge n} |X_k|$$

$$\le c + \sum_{k=1}^{T \wedge n} |X_k|$$

$$\le c + \sum_{k=1}^{T \wedge n} K$$

$$\le c + (T \wedge n - 1 + 1)(K)$$

$$ = c + (T \wedge n)(K)$$

I'm stuck. How can I approach this?

Comment: 1. $\sigma_k^2 = Var(X_k)$ is non-random.

Comment: 2. If $n<T$ then $|M^T_n|=|M_n|\le c$. If $n\ge T$ then $n\wedge T=T$ and $|M^T_n|=|M_T|\le |M_{T-1}|+|M_{T}-M_{T-1}|\le c+K$. In either event, $|M^T_n|\le c+K$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins 1 I think I get it: it's constant and is equal to the sum of those random variables almost surely so RHS is nonconstant and LHS is constant so surely they're not equal?

Comment: @JohnDawkins 2 Thanks! ^-^ Post as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying John Dawkins' comment:

[image]